# How to identify the originator of an URL call under iOS/iPadOS?

Tags: ios, proxy, url, multitasking, ipados

I am sometimes testing my apps on iPhone/iPad with Charles http PROXY to debug URL calls. I have noticed, that when I lock my iPhone and Charles is still running, I can see various URL connect calls to some sites in regular intervals. For some of the calls I can guess the app that is making the call, but some calls it does not ring a bell.

On Linux I have commands to find all open ports/connections and corresponding processes and I seek an equivalent way to do this on iOS/iPadOS.

How can I find the originator process or app for these calls?

Comment: Are you referring to how to do this via Charles Proxy?  The iPhone/iPad have no way of doing this natively.

Comment: What Linux commands are you using? You might be pleasantly surprised that iOS comes from the Unix heritage that predates Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a jailbroken iOS/iPadOS device, you can use the command "lsof" to find out which process has that specific port open.

You would run it like this:

```
lsof -n -iTCP
```

It would list ports that the process has open with the mark "(LISTEN)" at the end. Outgoing connections would be marked differently depending on their state, typically "(ESTABLISHED)", "(CLOSED)" or various wait states.